¿Como puedo agregar un filtro general en Django Admin Panel para uso MultiEmpresa?
Mi idea es agregar un combo box o un choice en la parte superior en donde se seleccione un pais y una empresa para el entorno de trabajo y que en base a esa selección se filtren los datos de las demás tablas las cuales tengan esos campos como llaves foráneas.
Alguien ha realizado algo similar?
dejo una muestra de mis modelos para saber si alguien me puede guiar en ese sentido.
Models.Py
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from smart_selects.db_fields import ChainedForeignKey
# Create your models here.

class Pais(models.Model):
    id= models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=100,verbose_name='Nombre del Pais:')
    moneda = models.CharField(max_length=5,verbose_name='Moneda en circulacion:')
    bandera = models.ImageField(upload_to='imagenes/',verbose_name='Imagen de Bandera:', null=True)       
    
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = ('Pais')
        verbose_name_plural = ('Paises')

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return "{}".format(self.nombre)
    
    
    def delete(self, using=None, keep_parents=False):
        self.bandera.delete()
        super().delete()

class Propietario(models.Model):        
    id= models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    id_pais = models.ForeignKey(Pais,on_delete=models.CASCADE,verbose_name='Codigo de Pais')
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=150,verbose_name='Nombre de Propietario')
    telefono = models.CharField(max_length=10,verbose_name='Numero de Telefono')
    correo = models.CharField(max_length=100,verbose_name='Correo de Contacto')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = ('Propietario')
        verbose_name_plural = ('Propietarios')

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return "{}".format(self.nombre)

class Empresa(models.Model):
    id= models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    id_pais = models.ForeignKey(Pais,on_delete=models.CASCADE,verbose_name='Codigo de Pais')
    id_propietario = ChainedForeignKey(
        Propietario,
        chained_field="id_pais",
        chained_model_field="id_pais",
        show_all=False,
        auto_choose=True,
        sort=True)
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=150,verbose_name='Nombre de Empresa')
    nombre_juridico = models.CharField(max_length=150,verbose_name='Nombre Juridico de Empresa')
    nit = models.CharField(max_length=20,verbose_name='NIT')
    direccion = models.CharField(max_length=250,verbose_name='Direccion Principal')
    numero_constitucion = models.CharField(max_length=10,verbose_name='Numero de Constitucion')
    fecha_constitucion = models.DateField(default=timezone.now(),verbose_name='Fecha de Constitucion') 
    fecha_inscripcion = models.DateField(default=timezone.now(),verbose_name='Fecha de Inscripion')
    correo = models.CharField(max_length=150,verbose_name='Correo de Contacto')
    telefono = models.CharField(max_length=10,verbose_name='Telefono de Contacto')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = ('Empresa')
        verbose_name_plural = ('Empresas')


    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return "{}".format(self.nombre)  
    
class Establecimiento(models.Model):
    id= models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    id_empresa = models.ForeignKey(Empresa,on_delete=models.CASCADE,verbose_name='Codigo de Empresa')
    numero = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Numero de Establecimiento:')
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=70,verbose_name='Nombre de Establecimiento:')
    fecha_apertura = models.DateField(default=timezone.now() ,verbose_name='Fecha de apertura:')
    direccion = models.CharField(max_length=150,verbose_name='Direccion de Establecimiento')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = ('Establecimiento')
        verbose_name_plural = ('Establecimientos')

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return "{}".format(self.nombre)
    
class UnidadMedida(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    id_pais = models.ForeignKey(Pais,on_delete=models.CASCADE,verbose_name='Codigo de Pais')
    descripcion = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name =('Unidad de Medida')
        verbose_name_plural =('Unidades de Medida')
    
    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return "{}".format(self.descripcion)
    
class CategoriaProductos(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    id_pais = models.ForeignKey(Pais,on_delete=models.CASCADE,verbose_name='Codigo de Pais')
    id_empresa = ChainedForeignKey(
        Empresa,
        chained_field="id_pais",
        chained_model_field="id_pais",
        show_all=False,
        auto_choose=True,
        sort=True)
    descripcion = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = ('Categoria Productos')
        verbose_name_plural = ('Categorias Productos')

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return "{}".format(self.descripcion)
    
class SubCategoriaProductos(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    id_cat_prod =  models.ForeignKey(CategoriaProductos,on_delete=models.CASCADE,verbose_name='Categoria:')
    descripcion = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = ('Sub Categoria Productos')
        verbose_name_plural =('Sub Categorias Productos')
    
    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return "{}".format(self.descripcion)
    
class Producto(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    id_pais = models.ForeignKey(Pais,on_delete=models.CASCADE,verbose_name="Codigo de Pais")
    id_empresa = ChainedForeignKey(
        Empresa,
        chained_field="id_pais",
        chained_model_field="id_pais",
        show_all=False,
        auto_choose=True,
        sort=True)
    id_establecimiento = ChainedForeignKey(
        Establecimiento,
        chained_field="id_empresa",
        chained_model_field="id_empresa",
        show_all=False,
        auto_choose=True,
        sort=True)
    id_unidad_medida = ChainedForeignKey(
        UnidadMedida,
        chained_field="id_pais",
        chained_model_field="id_pais",
        show_all=False,
        auto_choose=True,
        sort=True)
    id_categoria = ChainedForeignKey(
        CategoriaProductos,
        chained_field="id_empresa",
        chained_model_field="id_empresa",
        show_all=False,
        auto_choose=True,
        sort=True)
    id_sub_categoria = ChainedForeignKey(
        SubCategoriaProductos,
        chained_field="id_categoria",
        chained_model_field="id_cat_prod",
        show_all=False,
        auto_choose=True,
        sort=True)
    codigo = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    descripcion = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    combustible = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    idp = models.FloatField()
    precio = models.FloatField()
    costo = models.FloatField()
    activo = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = ('Producto')
        verbose_name_plural = ('Productos')
    
    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return "{}".format(self.descripcion)

Básicamente la estructura de filtrado tendría que ser
Pais
Propietario
Empresa
Establecimiento
El lugar donde quiero ubicarlo seria el siguiente

